# Why all are letters appending in a list only?

Tags: python

```
def up_low(s):
    a=[]
    b=[]
    
    for i in s:
        if i.upper():
            a.append(i)
            
        elif i.islower():
            b.append(i) 
            
        else:
            pass
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(f"No. of Upper case characters : {len(a)} ")
    print(f"No. of Lower case Characters : {len(b)}")
```

1.only uppercase letters should append in a
2.only lowecase letters should append in b

Comment: Compare your two method calls...

Comment: In your own words: where the code says `i.islower()`, why does it say `islower`, and not `lower`? What would it mean if it said `lower` instead? So, where it says `i.upper()`, does that make sense? What if it said `i.isupper()` instead? Did you try to read the documentation for these methods, in order to understand what they do?

Comment: The expression in `if i.upper()` must be `i.isupper()`, moreover, what is the definition of `s`?

Comment: upper() returns a new string with characters converted to upper case. lower() does the same for lower case characters. isupper() and islower() are the functions to be used here.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me it's my silly mistake in isupper() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if i.upper(): condition in your code is where the problem is. No Boolean value indicating whether the character is uppercase or lowercase is returned by the upper() function. The character is changed to uppercase instead.

To fix you can use isUpper():

```
for i in s:
        if i.isupper():
            a.append(i)
        elif i.islower():
            b.append(i)
        else:
            pass
```